# Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/docker-data/mongo': mkdir /docker-data: read-only file system?

Tags: docker

Запускаю docker образ mongod который скачал через docker pull

```
sudo docker run --name mongo_1 -d --env PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin  MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org --env MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org --env MONGO_MAJOR=3.4 --env MONGO_VERSION=3.4.10 --restart=always  -v /docker-data/mongo:/data/db:rw mongo:180918 mongod –auth
```

Но выводится ошибка 
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/docker-data/mongo': mkdir /docker-data: read-only file system.

Как разрешить запись в файловую систему контейнера?

Comment: вероятно, каталога `/docker-data/mongo` не существует.

Comment: В такой же ситуации, появляется точно такая же ошибка. Хотя папка существует и на неё стоят права 777.